# Is the following statement true of false? Prove or provide counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the following statement true of false? Prove or provide a counterexample

> $\forall m\in \mathbb{Z}\;\;  \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}\;\; (2mn < m + n)$

Do I just plug in two random two random $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$ to prove/disprove this?

Comment: Is the statement you want "$(\forall M\in\mathbb{Z})(\exists N\in\mathbb{Z})(2MN<M+N)$"?

Comment: It says $\forall m \in \mathbb{Z}$, so you cant prove by example. However, you can disprove.

Comment: Hint: Solve this for $n$...what do you notice about the required $m$...will it always admit and integer solution?

Comment: @Luiz , yes with parathesis

Comment: Hint:  you can rearrange the desired inequality to read $n(2m-1)<m$  so, at least if $m≥1$, all you want is $n< \frac m{2m-1}$  (and a similar expression holds if $2m-1<0$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One way is to prove that the result is correct is to note that $2mn\lt m+n$ if and only if $(2m-1)(2n-1)\lt 1$.  Now there are two cases to examine, $2m-1\gt 0$ and $2m-1\lt 0$.

*Added*: Without the algebra, one may notice that if $m\gt 0$, then $n=0$ works, while if $m\le 0$, then $n=-1$ works.